# Is Bugleweed vitamin supposed to be black?

Tags: micronutrients, coloration-discoloration, herbs, home-remedy

I have been using a vitamin supplement for hyperthyroid cat that includes bugleweed, also known as gypsyweed.

The vitamin liquid looks kind of strange. It is dirty brown with black fibers or moss-like substance. Is this normal?